# Ubuntu ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused

Tags: ssh

I am trying to install Hadoop3.0 on my laptop which is Windows 10. I installed ubuntu 16.0.4 on the same laptop. Hadoop installation is complete but I am not able to start the daemon as it is throwing me port 22: connection refused error. I tried to uninstall and reinstall SSH. Also, changed the settings in sshd_config file as well. Unfortunately, nothing seems to be working. I have been stuck on this for about a week. Would appreciate if you could help me on this.

Comment: There's far too little information here - did you install Ubuntu on the laptop as a separate (dual boot) system? in a VM? via Microsoft WSL? How did you configure the network? where are you trying to connect from, and how?

Comment: I installed it as a windows subsystem. I have followed the steps included in the link: https://www.windowscentral.com/how-install-bash-shell-command-line-windows-10. I installed Hadoop on my laptop through ubuntu. I am getting the error when I try $ ssh localhost from the prompt. I am new to Linux environment. Your suggestions will help me a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
sudo service ssh restart
ssh localhost
```

select option yes. You may get public key error

Then try

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -P '' -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
chmod 0600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Once done.

Try `ssh localhost`